# Selenium ChromeDriver - the HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL timed out after 60 seconds

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I am using the ChromeDriver in an nunit test to test whether a complex page loads:

```
public ChromeDriver Driver { get; private set; }

 [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions{};
        co.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
        Driver = new ChromeDriver( co) ;
        Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
        Driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
        Driver.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
        Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    }
```

As you can see I have tried to increase timeouts to 2 miutes everywhere yet when I run

```
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

against the page I get

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL timed out after 60 seconds.
```

The page does take longer than 60 seconds to load,  So how do I increase the 60 seconds ?

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace.

Comment: Did it help, the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase the `DefaultCommandTimeout` in [RemoteWebDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.cs). You can do it by using the `ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService, ChromeOptions, TimeSpan)` or `ChromeDriver(string, ChromeOptions, TimeSpan)` overloads

```
ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions{};

Driver = new ChromeDriver("path to ChromeDriver.exe", co, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
// or
Driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), co, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
```